# Telerik ReportViewer export

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a working Telerik report that I can export to various formats, but the client requested that on export to specifically to PDF, that one of the columns in a table no longer show up.

I can't find any events raised on export such that I can then programmatically modify the table, and it's not clear from reading the properties that this is even possible. Anyone know if there's a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that the feature you would like to implement does not come out straight forward from Telerik box. One way to achieve the desired feature is the following:

1. Hide the export to PDF button on your ReportViewer
2. Prepare a second report without the column/s that you would like to hide
3. Add a button to call the method to export the report which
   point to the one you have prepared without the column/s that you do not like to show.

The method to export the report programmatically is available [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/programmatic-exporting-report.html) or [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/faq-display-pdf-browser.html) in the Telerik documentation.